# Is it possible to use INDEX/MATCH (array formula) with OR ? Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not sure whether it is possible or not, but I believe the issue is worth asking. To cut it short, here is what I would like to achieve to avoid the use of a new column (group):

```
=MATCH(1;("B"=A:A)*(OR(criteria5=B:B ; criteria6=B:B));0)
```

[image]

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I'm not clear what your expected result is - can you expand?

Comment: I mean the following formula works perfectly:

    "=MATCH(1;(B=A:A)*(criteria5=B:B);0)"

But is it possible to do the same using OR for criteria like:

    =MATCH(1;("B"=A:A)*(OR(criteria5=B:B ; criteria6=B:B));0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `OR` because `OR` (like `AND`) returns a single result, not the required array - you can use + to simulate `OR` the same way * simulates `AND`, like this

`=MATCH(1;("B"=A:A)*((criteria5=B:B)+(criteria6=B:B));0)`